# Why is this site so inactive?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed a lot of inactivity here; there are next to no questions being answered or asked. Why is that? What can we as the members of the site do to change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is surely true that this community is not very active, the amount of unanswered questions is pretty low (less than 5%) and no reason to worry. Answers, especially good answers, take some time, so have a little bit of patience with the community.

P.S. You may also think of other means to elicit more and faster answers, like promoting your questions on other social media, or offering a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

This is a personal opinion, so take it with a grain of salt.

I think there are a few reasons for this, in no particular order:

- Making or studying constructed languages is not a common hobby.
- I'm pretty sure that most conlang enthusiasts enjoy sharing and getting feedback on their own creations, and Stack Exchange Q&A is not a good format for this.
- There isn't a standard way to get into the hobby and there isn't a common core of knowledge that everyone is supposed to know.

Also, peoples' interest might be narrower than the scope of the site as a whole. For example, I'm interested in things that make learning an auxlang as a second language easy or difficult and less interested in conlangs tied to a specific work of fiction.

There's also another perspective to consider. The question quality on this site is fairly high. Relaxing some of the restrictions inherited from Stack Exchange might increase traffic, but it would also change the character of the site.

Comment: I would note that reducing expectations of quality is a non-starter, simply because this is SE. Each forum represents SE as a whole within its broader community, and since SE itself seeks to be **THE** high quality Q&A site, it follows that all forums will strive for high quality. Essentially, high quality & low activity is better than low quality & high activity.